# Why does this ServerSocket in Andorid (attached to PC via USB/ADB) accept connections only once?

Tags: java, android, sockets, adb, serversocket

**Situation:** An Android phone has been connected to a PC via USB. Using the ADB command `adb forward tcp:35000 tcp:30000`, I succeed in forwarding a port.
I want the PC to send its system time to the Android phone every 5 seconds for an hour. To this end, I do the socket programming.

**The PC side as a client:** (I ignore the exception handling code.)

```
public void sendTime()
{
    class SendTask implements Runnable
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // Here: I store the host_socket in a member field which is: 
            // Socket host_socket = new Socket("localhost", 35000);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(this.host_socket.getOutputStream()); 
            oos.writeObject(msg);
            oos.flush();
        }
    }
    // Here: private Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    this.exec.execute(new SendTask());
}
```

**The Android phone side as server:**

```
public void getReadyForSync()
{
    ServerSocket server_socket = new ServerSocket();
    server_socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 30000));

    while (true)
    {
        final Socket client_socket = server_socket.accept();
        Runnable receive_task = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client_socket.getInputStream());
                Message msg = (Message) ois.readObject();
                SyncTimeFragment.this.onReceive(msg);
            }
        }; 
        // Here: private static final Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        exec.execute(receive_task);
    }
}
```

In addition, the ServerSocket is established in a separate thread from the main Android thread using `AsyncTask` and `new ServerTask().execute()`:

```
public class ServerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        getReadyForSync();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Problems:**

> In my test, the server socket in Android phone accepts connections from PC **only once**.

Specifically, some debug information is as follows:

(1) Each time (every 5 seconds) `sendTime()` is called, the `host_socket` reads:
`Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=35000,localport=56520]`

**Notice:** The `localport`(s) here are the same for all `sendTime()` calls in a single execution, but different across executions. (*I am not sure whether this information is important or not.*)

(2) The `server_socket` reads:
`Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=0,localport=30000]`

(3) The `client_socket` received (**only once**) by the `server_socket` reads:
`Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=43890,localport=30000]`

Comment: No. The server can accept many clients. But if you have only one client...

Comment: @greenapps However, the only client has invoked the `sendTime()` method many times (every 5 seconds for an hour). In other words, many connections from PC have been issued but only one (the first one) of them has been accepted by the server. Any ideas?

Comment: No. Not many connections. It't still the same connection. You are not closing and reconnecting for every call. If you would then put it in your code please. As it is now with `//new Socket` its unclear whats happening.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry, I don't understand quite well. Do you mean that I am using the same connection `host_socket: Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=35000,localport=56520]` every time? Does this mean I cannot send different messages by reusing a connection?

Comment: @greenapps Following your instruction, I have fixed the bug: create a new Socket in the method `sendTime()` instead of storing `host_socket` as a member field and reusing it. Thanks. However, I don't quite understand why we cannot reuse a connection. Would you mind giving some explanation in an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: If the local port changes, that means that each time there's a new TCP/IP connection created; do you want that?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I sounds that this would cause performance problem. Although it does not matter much to me, can we avoid creating new connection each time? It will be better to reuse existing connections.

Comment: Just want to say I noticed you said:

"In my test, the server socket in Android phone accepts connections from PC only once."

I was working on an application that communicated with the phone and encountered transferring data issues after re-using the "adb forward" (and newly adb reverse) sockets without killing them.

After having killed the adb forward/reverse sockets and recreating them each time since they didn't need to stick around after a while this was resolving "most" of my issues.

Thought I'd share my experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating `receive_task` the code returns to `final Socket client_socket = server_socket.accept();` So the server throws away the connection as the `run()` will only grab one message. You would have to made a `while` loop in `run()` too.

Comment: In the comments following the post, I fixed the bug in a "bad" way: create a new Socket in the method `sendTime()` every time instead of storing `host_socket` as a member field and reusing it. This would cause performance problem. @TassosBassoukos

Comment: It would also cause resource leaks; prevent this by just looping in the receive_task; don't forget to put everything in a try-finally to release the sockets...